# Access another pages inside extension from content script or background page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

everyone.
Can anybody tell me how I can access DOM of another pages in my extension from content script or background page? I tried to make a connection from content script to popup.html. But it doesn't work. But the same code works with background.html...
Here's the code I place in myscript.js:

```
function sendLast(){
  var result = document.getElementById('last_3212164');  //document.evaluate("//*[@id='last_3212164']", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
  alert(result.textContent);
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
}

var t=setTimeout("sendLast()", 3000);
```

Here is code from popup.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
        <script>
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("Got it!");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
  }
);

    </script>
  </head>
<body>
Here will be the values
</body>
</html>
```

This code is supposed to give alert "Got it" every 3 second. But It doesn't do anything, silence... I open Popup.html 1 sec after loading the main page.

Comment: Can you show code that doesn't work?

Comment: I've added it to the question. It's peace of code from google code site. The main question is how can access DOM of popup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If popup is currently opened then you can access its DOM from a background page. If you need it in a content script then you would need to send a request to a background page first.

Lets say you want to read a value of `test` input field from a popup inside a content script:

**content_script.js:**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "findElementInPopup"}, function(response){
    console.log("value:", response);
});
```

**background.html:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "findElementInPopup") {
        var winArray = chrome.extension.getViews({type:"popup"});

        //if popup is opened
        if(winArray.length > 0) {
            sendResponse(winArray[0].document.getElementById("test").value);
        }
    }
});
```

You would need to do all the DOM manipulations in a background page as trying sending whole `window` through a response back to a content script would result in an error (object structure is too complex for json serialization).

Comment: My content script is embedded into page. This pages is updated using AJAX and I'm trying to get values from this page every 1 sec for example. So, in my case I need to send data to background page first and then from background page write to DOM of popup? Really I don't care whether it's popup or other page. I just need to accumulate data and to get user csv file with this data. Can you tell me what is the best way to do this?

Comment: P.S. The popup is closed from beginning... So I get nothing from chrome.extension.getViews({type:"popup"});

Comment: @damluar If you need to write something to popup then why not just send a request directly to a popup and do everything there? Popup has to be open, closed popup is not accessible in any way (well unless you open popup.html yourself through ajax).

Comment: Thank you for help. Is there a way to accumulate values in a background page and then form csv and open it in new tab for example?

Comment: @damluar Your code looks ok, just replace all alerts with `console.log`, alerts don't work in popups and prevent js from execution.